# How to iterate over columns of a matrix?

Tags: python, numpy

In python if a define:

```
a = arange(9).reshape(3,3)
```

as a 3x3 matrix and iterate:

```
for i in a:
```

It'll iterate over the matrix's rows. Is there any way to iterate over columns?

Comment: Why would you like to iterate over columns (or rows)? What is your overall goal? Perhaps more straightforward means exists for that. Thanks

Comment: Simple Linear algebra transformations for example

Comment: Care to show an example? Why these transformations can't be done with matrices directly? Thanks

Comment: Any way to get the column number as an int when needed if I iterate like this?

Comment: @him229 `for index, row in enumerate(a):`

Answer (score 42, accepted):

How about

```
for i in a.transpose():
```

or, shorter:

```
for i in a.T:
```

This may look expensive but is in fact very cheap (it returns a view onto the same data, but with the shape and stride attributes permuted).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `a` is a well formed matrix, you could try something like:

```
b = zip(*a)
for index in b:
   ...
```

Comment: If a is large, using `zip` is very expensive compared to `a.T`. For example if `a` is 100x100, then zip is 5000x slower than taking the transpose. For the 3x3 case it's still 10x slower. It's generally a good idea to use numpy built-ins rather than treating ndarrays like python lists.