# map a function to all columns for Scipy/numpy matrix

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have a 40*4 matrix`M` and a vector`A` with 40 elements. I want to calculate the cosine distance between `A` and each column vector in M.

Do I really need to write like this?

```
 print [cosine(M[:,i],A) for i in range(A.shape[1])]
```

Or there's another better way to do this?

The document of cosine can be viewed here: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cosine.html#scipy.spatial.distance.cosine

Thanks!

Comment: Could you show M.shape and A.shape outputs. for (40,4),(40,1) your code provides 1x1 list instead of 4x1. for other variants - errors with alignement. better means faster, more beautiful or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps a more functional way would be to use [`functools.partial`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial) to bind the second argument of `cosine` to `A` and then use `map` to apply this bound function to the columns of `M`

```
map(partial(cosine,v=A), M.transpose())
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5515181/how-to-iterate-over-columns-of-a-matrix), Numpy has a Pythonic way to iterate over the columns of a matrix. This way, you could write:

```
print [cosine(column,A) for column in M.transpose()]
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems `scipy.spatial.distance.cosine` really only works for vectors. To efficiently compute cosine distances using vectorized expressions, do

```
normM = np.sqrt((M ** 2).sum(axis=0))
normA = np.sqrt((A ** 2).sum())
cossim = np.dot(M.T, A) / (normM * normA)
dist = 1. - cossim
```

Assuming `M.shape == (40,4)`, `A.shape == (4,)`, and neither is an `np.matrix`.

Comment: If efficiency is important this solution is 5 times faster than the others