# Is there a cleaner way to iterate over columns of a matrix with numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I use this to iterate over the columns of a numpy matrix:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.random.randn(4,3)
for c in A.T:
    print c.shape  # (4L,) => not a real column
    c = np.array(c, ndmin=2).T
    print c.shape  # (4L, 1L) => OK
```

**Is there a better way to iterate over columns, avoiding the redefinition inside the loop, and the double `transpose`:**

```
for c in A.T:
    c =  np.array(c, ndmin=2).T
```

**?**

NB: I have already read [How to iterate over columns of a matrix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5515181/how-to-iterate-over-columns-of-a-matrix).

Comment: `[A[:,[i]] for i in range(A.shape[1])]`? Or use `A[...,[i]] ` for generic n-dim cases.

Comment: What do mean exactly by iterating over columns? And why answers of the question you hyperlinked didn't answer your question? Please be specific.

Comment: You can replace `np.array(c, ndmin=2).T` by `c[:, None]` to get a proper 2-D column

Comment: @Basj Would encourage you to post your own findings alongwith the code (feel free to use it) if that worked.

Comment: My experience with numpy shapes is just trial and error, so I'm really not in a good position to write an answer about this... I don't know how numpy internally distinguishes shapes `(4,)`, `(4,1)`, `(1,4)`, I should have a look about this first.

Comment: @Kasrâmvd: I mean looping over all columns `c` of a matrix. Each `c` should be of shape `(4,1)` in my example.

Comment: You can do `for c in A.T[..., None]:` This will give you your columns directly.

Comment: This works indeed @PaulPanzer. Could you post it as an answer? (could you include a ref for `...` keyword?)

Comment: Using `c=....` inside a loop is a bad idea. It breaks the link between `c` and the source. If the new `c` is a view, it might not be so bad, as in `c=c[:,None]`. But that's another thing to watch out for.

Answer (score 2):

You can transpose and then add a dimension on the very right

```
A.T[..., None]
```

or, equivalently, add a dimension on the very left and then transpose

```
A[None].T
```

In either case you'll get a (3, 4, 1) shaped array which you can then iterate over.

You can read up on the indexing in general and the Ellipsis ("...") literal in particular in the numpy docs https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html